# Format fonts and individual cells in Tables?

Tags: tables, texshop

Is it possible to directly modify the fonts in a table ?

For example I have :

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table of Bla } \\
  \hline
  test & test2 \\
  yes  & no    \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to have the title `Table of Bla` in bold, is that possible ?

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Table of Bla}`

Comment: @egreg  
Can you please reply as answer to mark it as correct ? Would the same work for content inside each cell ?

Comment: For the content of the cell (and even the title of the table) you should use `\textbf{bold stuff here}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cells in a `tabular` environment form a group, so setting font attributes in one of them will not influence the other cells.

So the answer is

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Table of Bla} \\
\hline
test         & test2 \\
\itshape yes & no \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I've set the first cell in the third row in italics, just to show another example.

One can also use

```
\textbf{Table of Bla}
```

and

```
\textit{yes}
```

but this just makes TeX work harder. Of course you should use the `\textXX` form for *part* of a cell contents, for instance

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Table} of Bla} \
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This might be related due to formatting cells in a table, how can you assign a shade (or color) to a specific row ? Or shall I create a new question for this ?

Comment: @NLed Look at the `colortbl` package.